# Firebase Batch set with invalid data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Error Message: Function WriteBatch.set() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

I have a button that onclick runs the addQuotes function.

Where am I going wrong?

```
const addQuotes = async () => {
      let test = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.google.com/about',]
      const obj1 = Object.assign({}, test);
      const batch = writeBatch(db);

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => {
  var docRef = db.collection("col").doc(); //automatically generate unique id
  batch.set(docRef, obj1[key]);
});

 batch.commit().then(function () {
        console.log("hello")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the `data` param [should be an object (second argument to the batch.set method)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#parameters_1)

- Commented out the firebase methods invocation for running the code
  and show you the o/p

```js
// In your case when you do 
let test = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.google.com/about', ]
const obj1 = Object.assign({}, test);

console.log(obj1);


// and ignoring the unique id step


Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key, index) => {
  // var docRef = db.collection("col").doc(); //automatically generate unique id
  
  console.log(obj1[key]);  // here it is just the string value
  
  console.log({[index]: obj1[key]}); // here it is an object
  
  //when you do the bellow line
  // batch.set(docRef, obj1[key]); // value of obj1[key] is just string which is not the correct type 
  
  // may be you do something as below (key can be as you want it to be)
  // batch.set(docRef, {[index]: obj1[key]});  // index is added as key for the object which in now an object and should work
  
});
```

I used `{[index] : obj1[key]}` notation which is [computed property in object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Hope it's clear

Comment: Yes this works! I see I was passing in just obj1[key] where it should of been an object, Thank you!